# How to fill a structure defined in one .c file in a function defined in another .c without passing the pointer as an argument?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, fortran, extern

I have a C function (store_mode_ - defined in file_A.c) which is called in a Fortran code.

It looks like this..

```
// Create a global structure to populate with current mode frequencies
struct minos_modes current_modes;
static int nmode = 0;

void
store_mode_( int *n, int *l, double *w, double *U )
{
  if ( nmode == MODE_MAX )
    {
      printf( "[ store_mode_ ] Error: MODE_MAX is too small\n" );
      exit( 1 );
    }
  current_modes.mode_n[nmode] = *n;
  current_modes.mode_l[nmode] = *l;
  current_modes.mode_w[nmode] = *w;
  current_modes.mode_U[nmode] = *U;
  nmode += 1;
  current_modes.len = nmode;
}
```

I am trying to fill a structure with the values (n, l, w, U) passed as arguments in the Fortran call. The above code works when defined immediately above my main in File_B.c, which calls the fortran code within it.

However.. If I define the above function in file_A.c (the one that main isn't in) it doesn't work. I appreciate this is due to the lack of shared globals between .c files. I was wondering if there is a solution for this? 
Perhaps with extern, though I played a little with no success.

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not a problem description.

Comment: do you define and include these symbols from header files? during compile time the compiler needs to know that there's a store_mode symbol, then at linking time you will join the object files provide the binary with the definition of those symbols

Comment: You need to know where the structure is defined; that file will need to be linked into the executable.  Other files can include the header that declares the structure and then access it. The header should contain something like `extern struct minos_modes current_modes;` and will need to know the details of the structure definition too. The file that defines the structure should also include the header so the compiler can do cross-checking

Comment: Does file_A.c have an `extern struct minos_nodes current_nodes;` statement?

Comment: The question should include the exact error messages you get  (preferably include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) too)

Answer (score 1):

```
static int nmode = 0;
```

If you are including that line in both files, then you have two `nmode` variables, one in each file.  The `static` makes the symbol private to the *translation unit*.

Instead, you probably want

```
int nmode;
```

in one file, and

```
extern int nmode;
```

in the other.  (There's no need to initialize it to zero explicitly.  That's guaranteed for static storage.)